# How to detect NX/XD bit under Windows

Tags: windows, security, memory, central-processing-unit

I'm trying to find a way to detect (using software) if the system I'm on has ['No eXecute' bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit) capability.

Under Linux I would simply list the CPU features using /proc/cpuinfo but I found nothing in this regard on Windows. I tried CPU-Z and some other tools but none had NX bit information.

any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

wmic OS Get DataExecutionPrevention_Available

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/912923

Comment: Ok, DEP is the name used under Windows for anything related to memory protection as I can see. NX or XD capability is reported by this command.

Comment: Seems it shows if this function is turned on, not whether it is available.

Answer (score 1):

`coreinfo.exe` from Sysinternals Suite.

`coreinfo.exe | find "NX"`